# Unit testing - bad practice to pass repository into base class constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, constructor

In my application, most of my classes inherit from a Base class. There's also a repository class for data handling.

To make them testable, I've been doing this in my classes:

```
private IMyRepository _rep;

public MyViewModel()
    : this(new MyRepository())
{ }

public MyViewModel(IMyRepository rep)
{
    _rep = rep;
    DoStuff();
}
```

But is there any good reason - in terms of testability or functionality - that I shouldn't shift all that into the Base class and then just run it from the inherited constructor to get my repository before adding DoStuff() to the derived class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can put the repository into the base-class constructor

- if every class inherited from baseclass uses the **same** repository-type or
- if you use genric parameters like `MyBaseClase<ELementtype>` gets a `IRepository<ElementType>`.

I usually have different repositorys for different model-class so my customer-model gets a customer-repository and invoice-model gets a invoice-repository.

I would add the repository only to the baseclass if the baseclass has some functionality that needs the repository.

Comment: Thanks. The base class doesn't need the repository directly, but there are instances in the application where it would be useful for all the classes to be using the same repository, to avoid concurrency issues. All the classes do use the same repository type.